# CSS divide into two

Tags: html, css

Can someone guide me - In CSS, How can I split/divide a square'ish box into two so in a middle there a gap between them.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/spKMM/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="bigBox">
    <div id="leftBox"><div>
    <div id="rightBox"></div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#bigBox {
border-radius: 100px 0 100px 0;
height: 300px;
background: pink;
}

#leftBox {
    float:left;

}

#rightBox {
float:right;
}
```

EDIT: I know it can be done in other scripting lang but I want it in CSS and I know it is possible. Thanks.

Comment: You can't 'split' a div or "box" as you put it. You will need to create two divs. But first, I'd suggest you spend some time studying HTML and CSS.

Comment: @ChrisTill Oh I thought I can split them? I have created two divs as shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

This is a little sloppy but from what I gather from your question this is what you are after.

http://jsfiddle.net/spKMM/3/

**HTML**

```
<div id="bigBox">
   <div id="rightBox"></div>
   <div id="leftBox"><div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bigBox {
  width:800px;
  height: 300px;
}
#leftBox {
  float:left;
  height:300px;
  width: 390px;
  background: pink;
  margin:0;
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
}
#rightBox {
  float:right;
  height:300px;
  width: 390px;
  background: pink;
  border-radius:0 0 100px 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks I did try that but mine didn't seem to work.... http://jsfiddle.net/spKMM/5/

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="boxes" style="width:100%;">
  <div id="box1" style="float:left;width:47%;border:1px solid black;">BOX1 CONTENT</div>
  <div id="box2" style="float:right;width:47%;border:1px solid black;">BOX2 CONTEXT</div>
</div>`

This should give you the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In **CSS3** you can achieve something **similar** to *dividing* the `div`,

by using pseudo objects `:before` and `:after`.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/spKMM/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't split the box into two - I cant see a small gap goes between them?

Comment: if you resize the window, or set a smaller width on the `:before` and `:after`, you should actually be able to see quite a big gap =) But as aid above ... it is not really splitting anything, the CSS is just adding two additional virtual div's, that do not exist in the hrml, but you can style separately from the parent div. But this does not make so much sense anymore ... as you edited your question and added the left and right div inside ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean something like this?

```
#bigBox div {
    height: 300px;
    background: pink;
    width:45%;
}

#leftBox {
    border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
    float:left;
}

#rightBox {
    border-radius: 0 0 100px 0;
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qxjxj/

Comment: thanks that an idea! So instead of placing the `border-radius` in the `bigBox` you placed it in the two divs! :D

Answer (score 0):

Putting pixel is not helpful. And you dont need three CSS ids. My code is more fluid though user increase the width of browser window, the page will maintain the UI.
http://jsfiddle.net/spKMM/8/ see this code

here I used only two s in html

```
<div id="bigLeftBox"></div>
<div id="bigRightBox"></div>
```

And used only 2 CSS blocks, one is for left part, next is for right part.

```
#bigLeftBox {
    border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
    height: 100px;
    width:49%;
    background: pink;
    float:left;
}
#bigRightBox {
    border-radius: 0 0 100px 0;
    height: 100px;
    width:49%;
    background: green;
    float:right;
}
```